# Cygwin bash No such file or directory or command not found

Tags: bash, cygwin

I have shell scripts organized as:

```
--dir1
------file1.sh
------file2.txt
...........
------.dir2
----------file3.sh
..........
```

I create a symbolic link with

```
ln -s .dir2/file3.sh file3
```

Note that the link `file3` has `lrwxrwxrwx`

At dir1, when I run

```
./file3
```

I get
***bash: ./file3: No such file or directory***

while run

```
file3
```

gives me
***bash: files: command not found***

I have used dos2unix, and verified the

```
head -1 db.sh | od -c
```

returns
***0000000   #   !       /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h  \n***

Comment: What is your current directory when you executed `ln -s ...`? Is `.dir2/file2.sh` executable?

Comment: Created `file3` at `dir1`; yes **.dir2/file3.sh** has **-rwxrwxr-x+**

Comment: When you are in `dir1`, can you paste the result of this command : `ls -l * .dir2/*`

Comment: @Philippe the command lists (long) the files and their attributes in the current (dir1) and dir2 and it's child folders

Comment: may be `./file3.sh` is better ? The cygwin magic is only for EXE files...

Comment: What happens when you execute `.dir2/file3.sh`?

Comment: @glenn jackman same error **.dir2/file3.sh No such file or directory**

Comment: So it's not a problem with the symbolic link, it's a problem with the script. Does `bash` reside in `/bin`? Try `type -a bash`

Comment: Of course. I have multiple projects that use the same cygwin/bash on the same machine. The first created two projects has exactly the structure and shell files and work fine. Only difference is the database connection within the shell scripts. any newly created projects experience the same issue. and don't ask the database connection, we are far away from the point.

Comment: What happens if you run the script by `bash -x file3`?

Comment: Why are you doing a `head -1 db.sh`, when the program to be executed is `.dir2/file3.sh`?